# How to count the number of rows in a table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize in node.js. At the moment I can search multiple tables and produce the the results as data.  I have done so using the following code:

```
router.get("/alldata", (req, res) => 

Promise.all([chemical_bays.findAll(), electricals.findAll(), fire_services.findAll(), instruments.findAll(), mechanicals.findAll(), microwaves.findAll(), tools.findAll(), water_cays.findAll(), buildings.findAll(), substations.findAll(), fences_gates_cctv.findAll(), steam_plant_other.findAll(), information_technology.findAll(), ])
.then((data) => {  res.render('gigs', {gigs: [...data[0], ...data[1], ...data[2], ...data[3], ...data[4], ...data[5], ...data[6], ...data[7], ...data[8], ...data[9], ...data[10], ...data[11], ...data[12]] }) }).catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

However, I wish now to count the results and have them displayed, however, if I use the aggregate attribute, "count", I am receiving an error. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
router.get("/alldata", (req, res) => Promise.all([chemical_bays.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['chemical_bays.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), electricals.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['electricals.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), fire_services.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['fire_services.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), instruments.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['instruments.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), mechanicals.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['mechanicals.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), microwaves.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['microwaves.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), tools.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['tools.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), water_cays.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['water_cays.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), buildings.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['buildings.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), substations.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['substations.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), fences_gates_cctv.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['fences_gates_cctv.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), steam_plant_other.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['steam_plant_other.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), information_technology.findAll({attributes: ['id', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'count']],
group : ['information_technology.id'],
raw: true,
order: sequelize.literal('count DESC')}), ])
.then((data) => {res.render('gigs', {
    //gigs:data[0],
    //gigs2:data[1] 
    gigs: [...data[0], ...data[1], ...data[2], ...data[3], ...data[4], ...data[5], ...data[6], ...data[7], ...data[8], ...data[9], ...data[10], ...data[11], ...data[12]]
   })   
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

Comment: "an error"...and what error would that be, exactly?

Comment: I have deployed to Heroku and the page says "Internal Server Error". @ADyson

Comment: That's a generic message which could have a lot of different root causes. You need to examine error logs on the server to find out what the underlying exception was. If your application doesn't log errors then you need to set it up so that it does, otherwise you'll never be able to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
logging: console.log()
```

in your options (same level as raw). This will print the MySQL query in the app's log. You can then try running the same query in MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin and see if you have a clear error message.